# Log a user in without switching focus to it

Tags: windows-8.1, login, webserver, auto-login

I have a few programs that auto-start whenever I log into my user on my Windows 8.1 computer. Because some of these are servers (such as FTP and HTTP that I use to access my files when I'm away), they need to (almost) always be on. Because of this, I need to have my computer on all the time, which I know is not good for a computer that's used by my whole family throughout each day. So, I have my computer restart every day at 04:00 to make sure it's able to install updates, refresh itself, etc. Unfortunately, I have to log myself in every time this happens, so it's pretty much useless. I understand I can use the [registry](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_auto_logon.htm) to automatically log myself in, and then use the Event Scheduler to run the rundll32.exe lock command, but I don't want that because of my username and password being publicly accessible to anyone who gains access to the registry. How would I do this?

**TL;DR:** I have servers that auto-start when I login, so I leave my computer on 24/7 but have it restart every night. I need to manually log in whenever it does so or else the servers don't start. Using a registry hack does the job but puts my password out there for the world to see (or at least anyone who looks in the registry), so I need a better solution.

This is probably a bit vague, so let me know if I need to give any more information.

Answer (score 0):

To Turn On or Automatic Sign-in at Startup in Netplwiz

```
1. Press the Windows + R keys to open the Run dialog box, type netplwiz or control
userpasswords2, and press Enter.

2. If prompted by UAC, then click/tap on Yes.

3. Continue to next section.
```

[image: User Accoutns]

To Turn On Automatic Sign in for a Local User Account or Microsoft Account

```
1. Check the "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer" box. 
(See image above.)

  NOTE: If your PC is a member of a domain by chance, then the "Users must enter a user
  name and password to use this computer." box will not be available.

2.  Select the User Name of the local user account or Microsoft account that you want
to have Windows 8 log on to automatically at startup.

  NOTE: If this is for a Microsoft account, then you do not want to select the one that
  is only a member of the HomeUsers group. You would want to select the one listed that
  is part of both the HomeUsers and Administrators or Users group instead.

3. Uncheck the Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer box, and
click/tap on OK.

4. Enter the password of the selected local user account or Microsoft account twice,
and click/tap on OK.

  NOTE: If the selected local user account does not have a password created for it,
  then leave the password fields empty. Microsoft accounts will always have a password.
```

Comment: So with this, I would just have it lock right after logging in, correct? I'm going to try this now, thanks a lot! **EDIT:** Will other users also be able to log into their accounts on startup?